# Obtener latitud y altitud al pulsar en un mapa

Tags: javascript, html

Muy buenas.

Tengo un ejercicio pendiente que no sabría como plantear su estructura. El ejercicio seria el típico juego de adivinar donde esta localizado una ciudad en el mapa. Aparece una ciudad al azar de España y tenemos que señalar en el mapa donde creemos que está. Si donde se ha pulsado está a menos de 100km de distancia de la ciudad, acierta y sino pues falla.

Lo de calcular los km de diferencia entre latitud y altitud si lo tengo claro pero el único problema que tengo es que no se como insertar un mapa en mi web que solo te muestre el contorno de las comunidades autónomas y que al pulsar en el mapa, me devuelta la latitud y la altitud del punto seleccionado.

Hasta ahora los únicos mapas que he encontrado son los tipicos de google maps o apis parecidas pero lo único que me permiten es mostrar un mapa con una ubicación en concreto, no me deja pinchar para seleccionar una ubicación.

Habría que hacerlo con JS.

A ver si podéis echarme una mano con esto. :)

Comment: Lo mejor es que utilices una librería de JavaScript como OpenLayers o Leaflet que son para crear mapas. Mira la documentación para encontrar el método de obtener coordenadas:
https://openlayers.org/
https://leafletjs.com/

Comment: Antes de meternos en APIs complicadas: ¿te valdría simplemente mostrar un mapa de España completo como una imagen y pulsar sobre dicho mapa?

Answer (score 1):

Buen día amigo, Openlayers es una muy buena opción, en su pagina hay una solapa con ejemplos que te pueden resultar de mucha utilidad. mirá https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/

Acá por ejemplo podrás tomar los nombres de los paises a medida que lo clickeas

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
  <title>Box Selection</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://openlayers.org/en/v5.3.0/css/ol.css" type="text/css">
<!-- The line below is only needed for old environments like Internet Explorer and Android 4.x -->
<script src="https://cdn.polyfill.io/v2/polyfill.min.js?features=requestAnimationFrame,Element.prototype.classList,URL"></script>

<style>
  .ol-dragbox {
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.4);
    border-color: rgba(100,150,0,1);
  }
    </style>
   </head>
     <body>
        <div id="map" class="map"></div>
        <div id="info">No countries selected</div>
     <script>
      import Map from 'ol/Map.js';
      import View from 'ol/View.js';
      import {platformModifierKeyOnly} from 
        'ol/events/condition.js';
        import GeoJSON from 'ol/format/GeoJSON.js';
       import {DragBox, Select} from 'ol/interaction.js';
         import {Tile as TileLayer, Vector as VectorLayer} from 
      'ol/layer.js';
      import {OSM, Vector as VectorSource} from 'ol/source.js';


        var vectorSource = new VectorSource({
         url: 'data/geojson/countries.geojson',
    format: new GeoJSON()
  });


  var map = new Map({
    layers: [
      new TileLayer({
        source: new OSM()
      }),
      new VectorLayer({
        source: vectorSource
      })
    ],
    target: 'map',
    view: new View({
      center: [0, 0],
      zoom: 2
    })
  });

  // a normal select interaction to handle click
  var select = new Select();
  map.addInteraction(select);

  var selectedFeatures = select.getFeatures();

  // a DragBox interaction used to select features by drawing boxes
  var dragBox = new DragBox({
    condition: platformModifierKeyOnly
  });

  map.addInteraction(dragBox);

  dragBox.on('boxend', function() {
    // features that intersect the box are added to the collection of
    // selected features
    var extent = dragBox.getGeometry().getExtent();
    vectorSource.forEachFeatureIntersectingExtent(extent, function(feature) {
      selectedFeatures.push(feature);
    });
  });

  // clear selection when drawing a new box and when clicking on the map
  dragBox.on('boxstart', function() {
    selectedFeatures.clear();
  });

  var infoBox = document.getElementById('info');

  selectedFeatures.on(['add', 'remove'], function() {
    var names = selectedFeatures.getArray().map(function(feature) {
      return feature.get('name');
    });
    if (names.length > 0) {
      infoBox.innerHTML = names.join(', ');
    } else {
      infoBox.innerHTML = 'No countries selected';
    }
  });
</script>
```

Comment: De nada, ahí edité la respuesta, espero te sirva. Saludos